# Entity framework updates several records when FirstOrDefault() is used

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a rather strange problem which is scratching my head at the moment. I am using EF together with MySQL for a project and when I want to update a record on the database like this

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var record = (from d in context.Dictionary where d.CompanyName == companyName && d.Name == "Logo" select d).FirstOrDefault();
            record.Value = _path;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Then every record that has *d.Name == "Logo"* gets updated for some reason, which means that it ignores the *d.CompanyName == companyName* part. Anyone who has experienced the same problem or know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the value that is in comapanyName

Comment: The value in companyName is a string containing only one company name on which the record should be updated. But for some reason all other companies Logo gets updated as well

Comment: Please use primary key to update instead of Names which is far more consistent..

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't use EF Provider for MySQL often but I suppose it works.

The problem can be splitted in 2 parts, a select and an update. The select is fine, if you need to see what is the query you can split the select statement like this

```
var query = (from d in context.Dictionary where d.CompanyName == companyName && d.Name == "Logo" select d);
var record = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

and have a look to query variable (just point it in debug mode).

About your issue the only reason that I can immagine is that you did not configure the Dictionary class in the right way.
I mean, when you run context.SaveChanges an Update query is generated using the Key definition of Dictionary (the Where part of the query). If the key definition is wrong, the where clause will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this I hope this will help you.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var record = context.Dictionary.Where(x=> x.CompanyName == companyName && x.Name == "Logo").FirstOrDefault();
                record.Value = _path;

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: This one gives the same result unfortunately.

Comment: How's it possible u get multiple records by using FirstorDefault method u can use yor class name instead of var like this
 
Dictionary record = context.Dictionary.Where(x=> x.CompanyName == companyName && x.Name == "Logo").FirstOrDefault();